# Como exibir dados de varias tabelas no DataGridView?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, winforms, datagridview

Estou tentando exibir de varias tabelas no `DataGridView`, a partir de um banco de dados que mapeei pelo *Entity Framework*.

Exemplo, tabela pessoa, endereco.

Tentei usar `pessoa.BindingSource`, então vem a lista endereço, mas não consegui chamar os tipos de endereços `{logradouro, cidade, bairro, estado}`

A estrutura que a tabela Pessoa esta usando para definir os itens/dados da tabela é:

```
public virtual ICollection<enderecos> enderecos { get; set; }
```

Comment: Você deve criar um novo objeto contendo os atributos / colunas que devem ser apresentadas na GridView para expor um resultado "Tabular"

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que criar uma nova classe, para ser usada como um "`ViewModel`", ou utilizar objetos anônimos:

Classe:

```
public class PessoaViewModel
{
    public string Nome {get;set;}
    public string Endereco {get;set;}
}
```

Source:

```
var result = Pessoas.Select(x => new PessoaViewModel(){ Nome = x.Nome, Endereco = x.enderecos.First().Logradouro + ", " + x.enderecos.First().Cidade }).ToList();

dgv.DataSource = result;
```

Usando objetos anônimos:

```
var result = Pessoas.Select(x => new { Nome = x.Nome, Endereco = x.enderecos.First().Logradouro + ", " + x.enderecos.First().Cidade }).ToList();

dgv.DataSource = result;
```

> ps. Exemplo simples, sem tratamento de erros. É possível que a pessoa tenha mais que um endereço, logo você tem que decidir qual a lógica será usada para exibir.

Comment: Estou usando o Tipos Anônimos, mas gostaria de exibi-los com uma formatação, por exemplo o cep: _____- __ ou um telefone (__) ____-____. No banco de dados estão salvos como string com os números sem o pontos e traços.